# bulma custom colors and theming

Tags: css, sass, themes, bulma

I'm currently trying to do a mutliple theme design system with bulma as a base.
But i'm currently struggling with adding a multiple theme system.

I added this in my customstyle scss file but it doesn't seems to work

```scss
@charset "utf-8";


:root {
    --primary: red;
    --secondary: #068295;
}

body[class="light"] {
    --primary: #F7A800;
    --secondary: #068295;
}

body[class="dark"] {
    --primary: blue;
    --secondary: #068295;
}

$primary: var(--primary); // this works 
$background: blue;
$text-strong: red;

$secondary: #8BC91D; // this works but without theming
// $secondary: var(--secondary); // this doesn't work 
$secondary-invert: findColorInvert($secondary) !default;

$custom-colors: (
    "secondary":($secondary, $secondary-invert),
);

@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
```

when I run the node sass command to generate the css file
i can see the is-secondary properties generated when i don't use the variable but when i use a variable to define my $secondary variable the is-secondary properties are not generated

Comment: SCSS gets compiled, so the primary and secondary colors are "hardcoded" in, once you get the CSS. To work the way intended, you would need to compile two SCSS files, resulting in two CSS files, one with light colours and one with dark colours.

Answer (score 0):

The current main version of Bulma doesn't support css variables.

I made it work by using the css-variables branch.
`npm i https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/tree/bulma-v1-css-variables;`

First do the import like:

```
@import 'bulma/sass/utilities/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/base/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/elements/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/form/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/components/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/grid/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/helpers/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/layout/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/themes/default.scss';
```

themes/default.scss makes all the css variables based on the sass variables.

After that you can use CSS variables to modify the default values, so you can have a dark mode, theme switcher and other things.

```
:root {
  --bulma-danger-h: 190;
}
```